# Given a property to body element, give another property to element INSIDE body

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have all my `body` on one column.
But I would like my header (which inside of my body) to be on another column.

How can I select the `header` element and change its properties even tho the `body` element has another ones?

I have tried:

```css
html {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
}

body {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

header {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Web.</title>
</head>
<header>

    <p>Outside the body</p>

</header>
<body>
    <p>Inside the body</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well

Comment: Already edited, I can't make the header start on another column @Dominik

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want the header to be in the next column over is that right?

Comment: Yes, Indeed @Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to fix your HTML. The `<body>` tag wraps the content of the HTML document so you can't use it as a container inside your doc. I turned it into a `<main>` tag which is more like what you're looking for I gather.

Then I Specified the `grid-row-start` for both cells so that the cells don't move into the next row.

Purely for embellishment I added a `gap` and a background color so that you can see better what is happening. Those are not important for this to work.

```css
body {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
     gap: 1rem;
}

main {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    background: rgba(255, 125, 0, 0.2);
}

header {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    background: rgba(255, 125, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Web.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <p>Outside the body</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Inside the body</p>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```